# How to open a report using LWC navigation in a new tab?

Tags: lightning-web-components, navigation

I'm using the following code to open a report using a LWC card.

**JS controller**

```
navigateToReport(event) {
    // Navigate to the Contact object's Recent list view.
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__recordPage',
        attributes: {
            recordId: this.settings.businessStrikesReportId,
            objectApiName: 'Report',
            actionName: 'view'
        },
        state: { 
            fv0: this.account.data.fields.Id.value,
            fv1: event.target.dataset.id
        } 
    });
}
```

**HTML template**

```
<div class="slds-truncate">
   <a onclick={navigateToReport} data-id="Active">Active Business Strikes: </a>
</div>
```

When I test this, the report opens in the same tab. I tried using target="_blank" in  but it does the same.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it via:

```
navigateToReport(event) {
    // Make sure the event is only handled here
    event.stopPropagation();

    // Navigate to the Contact object's Recent list view.
    this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
        type: 'standard__recordPage',
        attributes: {
            recordId: this.settings.businessStrikesReportId,
            objectApiName: 'Report',
            actionName: 'view'
        },
        state: { 
            fv0: this.account.data.fields.Id.value,
            fv1: event.target.dataset.id
        } 
    }).then(url => { window.open(url) });
}
```

Note that this adds a promise evaluation "then" handler that takes the URL and opens it in a new tab. It also makes sure the event is only handled by this onclick handler.

Comment: I tried this but still doesn't work. Do you mean, I should add another handler for "then" part? I'm quite new to LWC and Javascripts is not my forte

Comment: The "then" handler is in the code sample I provided - did you try this along with the stop propagation? This works for us...

Comment: Yes, I did exactly that. 
Should I use any import directive to make the 'then' handler work?

Comment: No, no more than the imports you already need for the rest of it. I assume you extend the mix in appropriately?

Comment: Yeah, I did it like 
"export default class AccountDemeritsCard extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement)"

which is the correct way, I guess.

Comment: Sorry, this has me stumped.

Comment: I believe you need "this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]" instead of "this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]" to return a promise.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. One of those "copy, paste and update the OP code" issues...

Answer (score 7):

I know this is old and you have probably figured it out by now, but I thought I would answer this one as it seems to be one of the top results on Google.

Per the documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation), you can use the GenerateURL API to get just the URL of the record page. You can then navigate to the URL via window.open(url).

```
this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
    type: 'standard__recordPage',
    attributes: {
        recordId: '005B0000001ptf1IAE',
        actionName: 'view',
    },
}).then(url => {
     window.open(url);
});
```